# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from: when using ASIHTTP request

Tags: objective-c, ios5, asihttprequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASIHTTPRequest build / link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742775/asihttprequest-build-link-error)

Hii am just stared using ASIHTTP Request .I have included all the classes that are specified.When i run my app with no code it runs fine but when i include a piece of code its showing a linker error    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest", referenced from:
and clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is what i written

{
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
```

request=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request startAsynchronous];

```
[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(didReceiveDataSelector)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didFinishSelector)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(didFinishSelector)];


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, this is a linker problem rather than a code problem.  I'm not familiar with the ASIHTTP stuff itself, but you need to add it into the Build Phases tab for your target.  If it's distributed as source, put it in the compile phase or, if it's distributed as a static library, put it into the link phase.